# Array how to convert string to numbers except the operators

Tags: javascript

I have tried to convert the string type to numbers in array but the operators are in the way.

```js
let outputArray = ['3', '5', '7' ,'+', '*', '9', '-' ];
numoutputArray = outputArray.map(Number);
console.log(numoutputArray)
//[ 3, 5, 7, NaN, NaN, 9, NaN ]
```

I wanted to get the array as `[3,5,7,'+','*',9,'-']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this way...

```js
let outputArray = ['3', '5', '7' ,'+', '*', '9', '-' ]

numoutputArray = outputArray.map(v=>isNaN(v)?v:Number(v))

console.log( JSON.stringify( numoutputArray ))
```